# Spring servlet in web.xml with missing contextConfigLocation param-value

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a *web.xml* file with (among other things) a servlet that defines an **init-param** to specify the **contextConfigLocation**, but the **param-value** is **BLANK**?

Why is the developer doing this. I can't for the life of me find anything in the documentations for Spring 3.X that tells me what effect this has.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>restservices</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default the `DispatcherServlet` will load a xml file named **[servlet-name]-servlet.xml**.

This is when no `init-param` named `contextConfigLocation` is defined.

However in your case there is an `init-param` named `contextConfigLocation` defined, which tells the `DispatcherServlet` to load nothing but only delegate to the parent context (the one loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`).

So in short there is a difference between no `init-param` defined or an empty `init-param`.

See also https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-4746.

Answer (score 1):

it just because the developer had nothing to declare in the servlet configuration.
he had maybe defined all what he needs in the root context.

Comment: Then why even include the <init-param> at all?

Comment: I guess no need, try to remove it then

Answer (score 0):

Ah. Generally, the dispatcher servlet would follow the convention of searching for `servlet-name` - servlet.xml to load the WebAppContext. 
It might be (and this is just guess work because i dont know your config) that there already is a file `restservices-servlet.xml` which is

- loaded using the `ContextLoaderListener`
- Or imported in your `applicationContext.xml` ( or its equivalent)
- Or isnt needed, because all the beans for the Controller/ViewResolver
  are configured in your `applicationContext.xml`

Typically, the `DispatcherServlet` config (WebappContext) should contain the Controller/ViewResolver bean definitions.